# Our event has it's own brand and site, but I need users to create a profile on our main site

Tags: onboarding

We have a pretty successful event, but I've never been happy with the onboarding process.

We have a separate event and brand for our event, lets say www.event.com. In order to particpate, you must create a profile on our main site www.main.com, so that your profile can be distributed to other users.

What's the best way to handle pushing users to our main site to create their profile and make sure they know on which site they are creating an account?

- Should they just enter their email and name, then be sent an email to
  finish? (Seems like low conversion is possible.)
- Should we put a branded account creation box on the www.event.com page, and
  then forward them to www.main.com to finish their profile?
- Or should we just give them a CTA that sends them to www.main.com to start and finish the process?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can create an API on `www.main.com` and use the API to handle the registration on `www.event.com` site.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards I guess I should've added that it's more about being clear on which site you are creating an account, not so much about the technology used.

Comment: If you can use this API and keep users logged in between the two sites, does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Is it inherently obvious that www.main.com is the owner of www.event.com?

If you had a www.event2.com would people know that www.main.com is the parent?

If the account is going to be owned by www.main.com then you are going to need some sort of "Activate my account for event1, event3, but not event2" mechanism.

I think the best approach for you would be to either redirect them to www.main.com or use an API from www.event.com to register them for www.main.com.

The key thing you need to consider is the transparency of what they are signing up for:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwLiYz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

---

[Envato](https://account.envato.com/sign_up?to=themeforest) does this beautifully. Below is the create account page for ThemeForest:

[image]

Comment: This is a great example and something I was searching for myself.

It's somewhat obvious now, but one of my goals was to make it even more obvious.

Comment: @KyleS I'm glad you like it. I've been trying to find more examples but I'm coming up empty. Good luck with your site(s)!!